# Can I edit Mylyn tasks online similar to the task list view in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, bug-tracking, bugzilla, mylyn, connector

I know there are several connector options for linking Mylyn to online bug databases like Trac and Bugzilla, as well as some services through TaskTop.  Presently I'm using just a local database but would like the ability to edit my tasks via a web editor (but still maintain syncronization between Eclipse and the online service).  Ideally, I would get an identical layout to Eclipse's task list view (shown below), where I could move tasks around, create subtasks, etc.

Is there a connector/online solution that provides this kind of online interface?

[image: Mylyn Task List Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to get 10 users JIRA license for $10. You can run it in your environment and manage tasks either from Mylyn using JIRA connector or trough JIRAs own web interface. Another popular option is to run local instance of Trac.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, so to clarify, using JIRA, there is a web-based hierarchical task editor as shown above?

Comment: I did, thanks--and didn't see anything resembling a hierarchical editor akin to the Eclipse task view.  Have you seen such an online editor using JIRA?  Thanks!